# Given a natural number N, find the largest number not greater than N with monotone nondecreasing digits

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

Given a non-negative integer N, find the largest integer number that is less than or equal to N with monotone nondecreasing digits.

(Recall that an integer has monotone nondecreasing digits if and only if each pair of adjacent digits x and y satisfy x <= y.)

Example 1:
Input: N = 10
Output: 9
Example 2:
Input: N = 1234
Output: 1234
Example 3:
Input: N = 332
Output: 299
Note: N is an integer in the range [0, 10^9].

Hi, I am trying to implement the above problem and I am exceeding time limit in case of bigger integers. Could you tell me how can I optimize my solution? Thanks.

**Code :**

```
class Solution {
        public int monotoneNondecreasingDigits(int N) {

            int num = N;
            int quot=0,rem=0;
            List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<>();

            while( num>=0 ){
               if( checkMontone(num) )
                   res.add(num);
               if( res.size() == 2 ) 
                   break;
                num -= 1;
            }

            return Collections.max(res);
        }

        public boolean checkMontone(int num ){

            String s = Integer.toString(num);

            for( int i=1;i<s.length();i++ ){
                if( (int)s.charAt(i-1) > (int)s.charAt(i) )
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use any `List` as you can deal with digits of your number directly.

### Example

Let's consider a number `776`. Digits of this number are not monotone non-decreasing as `6 < 7` (each right digit can't be smaller than its left adjacent digit).

If we maximise a digit `6` and decrement its adjacent `7` then we'll get `769`. But its digits are not monotone non-decreasing. So, we should decrement the *leftmost* `7` and maximise `6` and `7` - `699`.

### Algorithm

1. Start checking digits of your number from left to right.

   1. If no right digit less than its left adjacent digit then the current number is the answer.
   2. If some digit `d_i` is larger than its right adjacent digit `d_i+1` then decrement a leftmost digit equal to `d_i`. Set all the digits following that digit to `9`.
2. Print the solution

### Sample Code

```
private static void printLargestMonoton(String number) {
    char[] chars = number.toCharArray();
    int i = 0;
    // find a position after which the requirement is violated
    while (i < chars.length - 1) {
        if (chars[i] > chars[i + 1]) {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }

    // if at the end then the number is already the valid one
    if (i == chars.length - 1) {
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(chars));
        return;

    }

    // find the left most position to decrement
    while (i >= 1 && chars[i - 1] == chars[i]) {
        i--;
    }

    // if the leftmost digit is 1 then mark with \0 so that to remove later 
    if (chars[i] == '1') {
        // get rid of this char later to avoid a leading zero
        chars[i] = '\0';
    } else {
        chars[i]--;
    }

    // maximise all the digits to the right of the previous digit
    for (i = i + 1;i < chars.length; i++) {
        chars[i] = '9';
    }

    System.out.println(String.valueOf(chars).replace("\0",""));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] numbers = new String[]{"10", "1234", "332", "12214512", "11110"};

    for (String number : numbers) {
        printLargestMonoton(number);
    }
}
```

**Input**

> 19
>
> 1234
>
> 332
>
> 12214512
>
> 11110

**Output**

> 9
>
> 1234
>
> 299
>
> 11999999
>
> 9999

Answer (score 0):

Start by copying the input. We'll modify this copy to get the answer.

```
1. Look at each pair of adjacent digits of the input (from left to right). 
2. Find the first pair which is decreasing
3. Let d be the left digit of this pair. 
4. Find the first digit in your copy which is equal to d.
5. Decrement this digit by 1 in the copy.
6. Replace each digit to the right of the decremented digit with 9 in the copy.
```

E.g.,

```
input:  12214512
output: 11999999

input:  10
output: 09
```

run time O(digits) = O(log N)

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String returnLargestMonotonChars(String number) {

    char[] numberAry = number.toCharArray();
    // start from right side of element.
    for (int index = numberAry.length - 1; index > 0; index--) {
        // If current index number is less than previous then decrease previous by 1
        if (numberAry[index - 1] > numberAry[index]) {
            numberAry[index - 1] = numberAry[index - 1] -= 1;
            // After decreasing previous element make all element value = 9
            for (int i = index; i < number.length(); i++) {
                numberAry[i] = '9';
            }
        }
    }

    return String.copyValueOf(numberAry);
}
```

Tested with all inputs mentioned in question and in answered by @Anatolii.